# change limit of meta description length for crawlers

Tags: javascript, php

I have created a static website. Each page was created by manually coding. Now when I checked out Bing crawlers report. They refused to index by saying that the length of the meta description is more than 160 characters. I am unable to (because pages are too much) modify each file to edit meta descriptions under the required limit. Is there any way to show only 160 characters to the crawler by any script?
Or any other way so that Bing index my website.

Note that every page has a .php extension and the rest of everything in it is not linked to the database.

Comment: No, you are not in control of how a crawler scrapes your page

Comment: but why, when we are generating webpages in Q&A website with script, then why we can't control a specific section of a webpage with script

Comment: You said the site in question was made of static pages, not generated dynamically

Comment: Are you sure that they are refusing to index your site/page, or is there just a warning saying that your description is too long? The only thing that uses the meta description is a crawler (unless you have something proprietary) so why would you want to change it for them only? Just change it. That said, I've never heard of the major engines not indexing a page based on that field, they usually just ignore it if they think it is too spammy/verbose and write their own.

Comment: @ChrisHaas they are giving warning but not indexing a single webpage from last 3 months

Comment: Are you able to post a redacted screenshot of what you are seeing in the Bing Webmaster Tools? How many characters are we talking about, btw, 161 or 10,000? As to changing the description dynamically, I doubt JavaScript will be enough to do it, you'll probably need a pre-render language which is pretty much PHP for you. You can [identify Bing by their UA](https://www.bing.com/webmasters/help/which-crawlers-does-bing-use-8c184ec0). It sounds like these static pages are generated, so I'd just change the generation logic.